# Values selected from the database table returns nil

Tags: clojure

I'm really new to clojure and I'm trying to select values from the database. It does select the values(I think) though it only returns nil

I tried following the tutorial in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/clojure/clojure_databases.htm

Here is my code

```
(ns hello.core_test) 

 (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))


  (def mysql-db {
      :subprotocol "mysql"
      :subname "//localhost:3307/blink"
      :user "root"
      :password ""})
        (println (sql/query mysql-db
      ["select firstName from users"]
       :row-fn :firstName))
```

And it returns

```
(nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
```

(The database contains 9 variables)

[Here is the picture of my column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbroV.png)

Edited. Apparantly if I remove the

> :row-fn :firstName

And replace it with

> :row :firstName

It returns in a format like this

> ({:firstname Angel} {:firstname Austin} {:firstname enrico} {:firstname wilzen} {:firstname keith} {:firstname Joshua} {:firstname Ron Andre} {:firstname Allen Jay} {:firstname Ivan})

Comment: What do you get if you remove `:row-fn :firstName`?

Comment: And this code isn't valid. Your `ns` macro ends before the `:require`. Please post your actual code.

Comment: ^Uhm I think it was a pasting problem here in stack overflow. My name space covers the :require.

Comment: If I remove the :row-fn :firstname.    It returns in a {:firstName Value} format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clojure.java.jdbc` converts columns by default like that `(-> column-name clojure.string/lower-case keyword)`, you already partially answered it by yourself showing result without `:row-fn`.

Right now, using `[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.7"]` this works for me:

```
(sql/query mysql-db ["select firstName from users"] {:row-fn :firstname})
```

if you don't want auto conversion:

```
(sql/query mysql-db ["select firstName from users"] {:identifiers identity :keywordize? false})
;; => ({"firstName" "one"} {"firstName" "two"} {"firstName" "three"})
```

Comment: Thank you. Im trying to find the updated version of JDBC now :D